# Set a condition from inside of a loop Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

```
     <ul>
        {% for bm in user.bookmarks %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ bm.url }}">{{ bm.description }}</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li>This user has not added any bookmarks yet.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

Is there a way to set a condition from inside of the loop 
I mean if 'for loop' doesnt have any result the ul tag dont generate into page

The whole idea is preventing putting empty tag in the page
I know I can put another if expression outside but It is so complicated for maintenance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the `ul` tags inside the loop, and use the `loop.first` and `loop.last` variables to control them.

```
{% for bm in user.bookmarks %}
  {% if loop.first %}
    <ul>
  {% endif %}
      <li>
          <a href="{{ bm.url }}">{{ bm.description }}</a>
      </li>
  {% if loop.last %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
   This user has not added any bookmarks yet.
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, my code generates li as many as objects in the user.bookmarks
but your code generate only 1 li, also what does mean putting if only around opening tag and closing tag seperately ?

Comment: maybe I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if user.bookmarks %} 
<ul>
        {% for bm in user.bookmarks %}
            <li>
                <a href="{{ bm.url }}">{{ bm.description }}</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li>This user has not added any bookmarks yet.</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% enfif %}
```